# Using Telerik RadGrid how to hid a GridHyperLinkColumn from the client side?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using the Telerik RadGrid and I'm doing client side databind. Here is my Grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid_Assignments" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                     AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" >
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
        <MasterTableView NoMasterRecordsText="No assigments found for the search criteria.">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Customer Name" DataTextField="CustomerName" Target="_customer"
                                             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Modules/DataEntry/ProviderContact/Edit.aspx?id={0}"
                                             DataNavigateUrlFields="CustomerID" SortExpression="cust.Name" UniqueName="cust.Name"
                                             HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProviderName" HeaderText="Provider" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" />
                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="SurveyType,EvaluationID,SurveyID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Modules/AssignmentPortal/Evaluation/Enter{0}.aspx?EvalID={1}&sid={2}&menu=false" DataTextField="SurveyName" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" HeaderText="Survey Name" SortExpression="s.Description" Target="_survey" UniqueName="s.Description" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="WorkPhone" UniqueName="cust.WorkPhone" SortExpression="cust.WorkPhone" HeaderText="Work Phone"
                                         HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Email" DataTextField="Email" UniqueName="cust.Email"
                                             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="mailto:{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="Email" SortExpression="cust.Email"
                                             HeaderStyle-Width="300px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NoteDateTime" HeaderText="Last Note Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}"
                                         HeaderStyle-Width="150px" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NoteText" HeaderText="Last Note" UniqueName="cln.NoteText"
                                         HeaderStyle-Width="400px" />
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <DataBinding Location="/AjaxServices/SearchService" SelectMethod="GetAssignmentsSearchResults" />
            <ClientEvents OnCommand="showLoadingPanel" OnDataBound="OnClientDataBound" OnDataBinding="OnClientDataBinding" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

I want to be able to hid the GridHyperLinkColumn with the HeaderText="KLAS Maps" when the DataNavigateUrlFields of SpatialCoordinatesKLASID is NULL. I just want an empty column.

I can't use the traditional way using the server side OnItemDataBound event. Because this is loading on the client side.

How can I do this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with below code/demo.

```
 function DataBound(sender, args) {

            var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
            if (grid) {

                var IsColumnHaveData = false;
                var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var Rows = MasterTable.get_dataItems();
                for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = Rows[i];


                    if (row.get_dataItem().EmployeeName != null) {
                        IsColumnHaveData = true;
                    }

                }


                var Columns = MasterTable.get_columns();
                for (var i = 0; i < Columns.length; i++) {
                    var column = Columns[i];
                    if (column.get_uniqueName() == "EmployeeName") {
                        column.set_visible(IsColumnHaveData);
                    }
                }

            }


        }



<ClientSettings>
            <DataBinding Location="http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc" SelectMethod="GetData"
                SortParameterType="Linq" FilterParameterType="Linq">
            </DataBinding>
            <ClientEvents OnDataBound="DataBound" />
        </ClientSettings>
```

Please applied above code in below link code/demo.

[RadGrid with WCF Rest Service](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/08/radgrid-with-wcf-rest-service.html)

Hide particular Link.

function DataBound(sender, args) {

```
            var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
            if (grid) {

                var IsColumnHaveData = false;
                var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var Rows = MasterTable.get_dataItems();
                for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = Rows[i];
                    row.get_cell("EmployeeName").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if you wanted to hide a hyperlink item within a column? Can you do it from this DataBound function?

Answer (score 0):

I would use unobtrusive JavaScript via jQuery's onload.  Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxTuw/1/).

You'll need to analyze the generated HTML to make the right function.